# Cannot run the event loop when another loop is running

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-federated

RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running

Trying to setup tensorflow_federated in my local. All import versions are right:

CUDA = 10.1,

python = 3.6.9,

tensorflow = 2.2.0,

tf_federated = latest

This error is not happening in google Colab. But, happens in my local machine when I am trying to do any federated computations. I get the runtime error: 
RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-9c097e9baec9> in <module>
----> 1 tff.federated_computation(lambda: 'hi')()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tflocal\lib\asyncio\base_events.py in run_forever(self)
    426         if events._get_running_loop() is not None:
    427             raise RuntimeError(
--> 428                 'Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running')
    429         self._set_coroutine_wrapper(self._debug)
    430         self._thread_id = threading.get_ident()

RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running
```

Comment: Also, tried this: https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/docs/tutorials/README.md
My kernel just gets killed after running - nest_asyncio.apply()

Answer (score 1):

I got a very similar error when copy+pasting the [tensorflow-federated tutorial code](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated) into a local Jupyter notebook on Mac OS. I solved it by importing and applying `nest_asyncio` in addition to `tf` and `tff`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_federated as tff
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

...as suggested in **step 2** of the separate [tensorflow github tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/docs/tutorials/README.md) that OP linked above in a comment. Step 1 did not help me at all (and I doubt it will be of much help to those who already managed to install tensorflow_federated using e.g. some combination of `conda` and `pip`, in that order).

Comment: In case it helps, I installed with:
`conda create -n tff jupyter tensorflow;`
`conda activate tff;`
`pip install --upgrade tensorflow-federated;`.

This brings `nest_asyncio` with it, which is why Step 1 of the GitHub page linked above didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete `import nest-asyncio`

Comment: Should I refrain from using nest_asyncio? But in the documentation they have asked to use that https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/docs/tutorials/README.md